# Creating auto-update by Wix Sharp

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, auto-update, wixsharp

I have an installer created using Wix Sharp. Sometimes the application has to be updated, and it is important for me to find the way to do it. I think that the best way is to create one more app "App updater", which will check the version of the application, and if there is a new version it will download and install it. How can I create updater .msi using Wix Sharp? And where do I have to upload my .msi updater to be checked by the "App updater"? Here is the code:

```
    static void Main()
    {


        var project = new ManagedProject("MyProduct",
                         new Dir(@"%ProgramFiles%\My Company\My Product",
                             new Files(@"C:\Users\1\source\repos\ParentControl\ParentsControl\*.*")));

        project.GUID = new Guid("6fe30b47-2577-43ad-9095-1861ba25889b");

        project.ManagedUI = ManagedUI.Empty;    //no standard UI dialogs
        project.ManagedUI = ManagedUI.Default;  //all standard UI dialogs

        //custom set of standard UI dialogs
        project.ManagedUI = new ManagedUI();

        project.ManagedUI.InstallDialogs.Add(Dialogs.Welcome)
                                        .Add(Dialogs.Licence)
                                        .Add(Dialogs.SetupType)
                                        .Add(Dialogs.Features)
                                        .Add(Dialogs.InstallDir)
                                        .Add(Dialogs.Progress)
                                        .Add(Dialogs.Exit);

        project.ManagedUI.ModifyDialogs.Add(Dialogs.MaintenanceType)
                                       .Add(Dialogs.Features)
                                       .Add(Dialogs.Progress)
                                       .Add(Dialogs.Exit);

        project.Load += Msi_Load;
        project.BeforeInstall += Msi_BeforeInstall;
        project.AfterInstall += Msi_AfterInstall;

        //project.SourceBaseDir = "<input dir path>";
        //project.OutDir = "<output dir path>";

        project.BuildMsi();
    }

    static void Msi_Load(SetupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsUninstalling)
        {
            var w = new Ask();
            if(w.ShowDialog()!=DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bad password!");
                e.Result = ActionResult.SkipRemainingActions;
            }

        }
        if (!e.IsUISupressed && !e.IsUninstalling)
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Load");

    }

    static void Msi_BeforeInstall(SetupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsUISupressed && !e.IsUninstalling)
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "BeforeInstall");
    }

    static void Msi_AfterInstall(SetupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsUISupressed && !e.IsUninstalling)
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "AfterExecute");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at adding an updated to your app? wyupdate https://wyday.com/wyupdate/ handles detecting updates, downloading and restarting your app.